# RoR Expanded Form with JS Only submit One Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have this JS code, to add more fields if necessary, **but it's inserting into database only the last ROW added**, there are no codes in  my controller pointing to this, i think there should be but i don't know which or how to do it.

tasks.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $(".adicionar").click(function(){
 linha = $(".linha:first").clone();
 $(".tabela").append("<tr class='linha'>"+$(linha).html()+"</tr>");
 remover();
  });
});

 function remover() {
  $(".remover").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
 }
```

This is relato form  => http://pastebin.com/G63SzgZH
This is the controller => http://pastebin.com/gsY9KvVa

and model

```
class Relato < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :cliente
belongs_to :projeto
belongs_to :local
belongs_to :task
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it adds only one row in the database.... In your controller,

```
def new
  @relato = Relato.new
end
```

@relato can save only one record in the database. If you want to add more rows, then you have to create more instances of Relato.new...... There is no fault in your javascript. Its the issue with your controller....

Comment: one more thing is.... your last row is only saved to database, as the previous rows are overwritten by the last row...

Comment: Thanks, Could you please help me in how to create this instances , there are some like 5.times.Relato.new?

Comment: This is relato form => http://pastebin.com/G63SzgZH This is the controller => http://pastebin.com/gsY9KvVa

Comment: May i know, what this buttons are... <td><%= f.button 'Remover', type: 'button', class: 'remover' %></td> and <%= f.button 'Adicionar', type: 'button', class: 'adicionar' %>. what they do?

Comment: They call the function to Clone a Node and remove

Comment: Im really sorry Carlos.. As far as i know you cannot submit more than one form at a time....I mean by clicking submit button you cannot save more than one record.....